# How to add option to display @tags in Javadoc comments

Tags: java, javadoc

I have two own Annotations that I use for different fields and methods alongside the `@Deprecated` annotation. However, unlike the `@Deprecated` annotation, which can be displayed in the Javadoc comment itself with a description, is it not possible for me to do this with my own annotations.

Small example:

```java
/**
 * Sends "bar".
 *
 * @deprecated Use {@link #sendFooBar()} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
@MyAnnotation // I want to add a description to this annotation in the comment above
public void sendBar(){
    System.out.prntln("bar");
}
```

So my question is what I have to do, in order to display the annotation in the comment itself and to provide comments on it.

I can't just add it into the comment as it would be seen as a "wrong tag".

To clarify: I don't want to *just* display the @ symbol in the comment. I know how to do this.
I want to have documentation (description) in the Javadoc comment similar to the one available for the `@Deprecated` annotation.

The annotations themself have the `@Documented`, `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` and the `@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})` annotations attached to them.

Comment: @Jason I do not search for how to escape the @ Symbol. I search for how to have a description of the annotation in the Javadoc comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to use self-defined annotations in javadoc the way you think. This becomes more obvious if you write the annotations [per specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html). The javadoc `@deprecated` **tag** is written lowercase whereas the [`@Deprecated` **annotation** of the Java Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.6) is written capitalized.

This is due to the fact that the javadoc `@deprecated` tag comments on the deprecation of the underlying method and/or constructor rather than representing the Java `@Deprecated` annotation itself. You're therefore not able to use the annotation in javadoc the way you intended by default.

However, it IS possible to introduce custom tags to javadoc. How to do so is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#tag). You might also consider mentioning the implications your annotation might have somewhere else in the javadoc comment. To safely escape your annotation's name, just use the `{@code ...}` construct.